# Зацикливается анимация ожидания

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! На сайте после нажатия на кнопку происходят определенные действия, с помощью `ajax` запроса. Пока ждем ответ от сервера показывается анимация, после того как пришел ответ анимация скрывается. Реализовано это так:

```
function send(...)
  {
                showLoaderIdentity(); //Запускаем анимацию
                $.ajax({
                    ...
                    success: function(html){

                                hideLoaderIdentity(); //Скрываем анимацию

                });

  }
```

//////////// анимация ////////////////

```
  function showLoaderIdentity()
  {
      $("#loader-identity").show("100")
  }

  function hideLoaderIdentity()
  {
     $("#loader-identity").hide();
  }
```

Проблема в том что если на кнопку нажать быстро, несколько раз подряд, то анимация зацикливается и больше не исчезает

Comment: ну можешь делать disable/enable кнопки заодно, раз так

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, можете объяснить как это работает или дать ссылку на какой-нибудь ресурс?

Comment: у кнопки есть атрибут https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_disabled  .... устанавливаешь при клике, чтоб нельзя было кликнуть и всё. после запроса - убираешь атрибут...

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, не помогло( Свойство `disable` добавляется, но зацикливание все равно происходит, если быстро нажимать

Comment: Вы покажите, куда и и как вы добавили `disable`.

Comment: Можно использовать метод .off() который удаляет обработчики событий, назначенные методом .on() ну надо немного переделать функции...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно добавлять флаг с пометкой 'working' вот таким образом -
перед функциями создать глобальную переменную

```
var checkFlag;
```

а в функции send(...)  проверять задан ли флаг 'working'

```
if(checkFlag !== 'working'){
    showLoaderIdentity();
    checkFlag = 'working';
}
```